# GroupBy using select columns with apply(list) and retaining other columns of the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
data={'order_num':[123,234,356,123,234,356],'email':['abc@gmail.com','pqr@hotmail.com','xyz@yahoo.com','abc@gmail.com','pqr@hotmail.com','xyz@gmail.com'],'product_code':['rdcf1','6fgxd','2sdfs','34fgdf','gvwt5','5ganb']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['order_num','email','product_code'])
```

My data frame looks something like this:
[Image of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JwBY.png)

For sake of simplicity, while making the example, I omitted the other columns. What I need to do is that I need to groupby on the column called `order_num`, `apply(list)` on `product_code`, sort the groups based on a timestamp column and retain the columns like `email` as they are.

I tried doing something like:

```
df.groupby(['order_num', 'email', 'timestamp'])['product_code'].apply(list).sort_values(by='timestamp').reset_index()
```

Output: [Expected output appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5zaE.png)

but I do not wish to groupby with other columns. Is there any other alternative to performing the list operation? I tried using `transform` but it threw me size mismatch error and I don't think it's the right way to go either.

Comment: Please post a copy-pasteable line of creating a sample of your df. Also post a copy-pastable like of the required result df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a lot another columns and need grouping by `order_num` only use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column filled by lists and then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by column `order_num`, last if necessary sorting:

```
df['product_code']=df['order_num'].map(df.groupby('order_num')['product_code'].apply(list))

df = df.drop_duplicates('order_num').sort_values(by='timestamp')
```

Comment: I don't want to have email in the groupby clause here. If I don't do that, then the email is never included in the resultant.

Comment: @yorunome - Answer was edited, can you check?